# Is it possible to determine the nuclear spin with the hyperfine structure experimentally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I was wondering if there are experiments that allow to determine the nuclear spin with the  [hyperfinestructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure),
since it interacts with the magnetic moment of the nucleus there must be a correlation.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here are a couple of thoughts off the top of my head, could be wrong about some of this. These days the ground-state spins of stable nuclei are all known. Therefore this technique would only be of much interest if it was usable for unstable nuclei or excited states. I don't think it will work for excited states (unless they're very long-lived), and I would think you would need a macroscopic sample of the material, which is normally impractical with unstable nuclei. If you did have a macroscopic sample, would NMR be easier?

Comment: You might be interested to know that one of the first clues for the existence of deuterium involved observation of the hyperfine structure in the spectral lines. https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2915259